# VBA Cannot Refer To Range In Sheet That Exists Prior To Code

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently building some code that creates a bunch of formatted data in one worksheet, the active worksheet, then transfers that data to a new worksheet.

The problem is that when I try to specify the sheets by name, it doesn't work if the sheet existed prior to the code running.

So, in the code below, I get the error "'Range' of obect '_Worksheet' failed" at the line ".Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(7,3)).Interior.Color = RGB(100,100,100)" only if the "Topline" worksheet existed before running the code. If I delete the worksheet and let the code add and name the "Topline" worksheet, I get the same error but at line "Data.Range(Cells(x + 2, 1), Cells(x + a, 3)).Copy"

I've tried googling around but am completely at a loss for why this code only works on worksheets that didn't exist before running it. Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm almost willing to bet the answer is something obvious.

Here's the code that's troubling me:

```
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Topline" Then TE = True
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Data" Then DE = True
Next i

If TE = False Then Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Topline"
If DE = False Then ActiveSheet.Name = "Data"

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Topline" Then Set Topline = Worksheets(i)
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Data" Then Set Data = Worksheets(i)
Next i

With Topline
    .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(7, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
    With .Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 3))
        .Merge
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Value = "Total"
    End With
    With .Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(5, 3))
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    .Cells(1, 1) = "Topline"
    .Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
    .Cells(4, 2) = "Count"
    .Cells(4, 3) = "Percent"
End With

Data.Range(Cells(x + 2, 1), Cells(x + a, 3)).Copy
Topline.Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(a + 6, 3)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
```

Comment: You need to fully qualify all uses of a range. See how you did `Data.Range(...)`? Do the same with `Cells`. I.e. `Data.Range(Data.Cells(x + 2, 1), Data.Cells(x + a, 3)).Copy`.  And in your `With` statement, you need to add the `.` before `Cells`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have unqualified Range references. When you refer to any Range object without first specifying the worksheet, it's unqualified. Those references follow rules behind the scenes and use objects with underscores in them. So you might get errors referring to `_Worksheets` or `_Global`.

An unqualified reference in a sheet's class module will refer to that sheet. All other unqualified references (ThisWorkbook, standard module, userform) will refer to the Activesheet. This

```
With Topline
    .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(7, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
End With
```

is like saying

```
Topline.Range(Activesheet.Cells(1, 1), Activesheet.Cells(7, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
```

Since there is not range on Topline that includes cells from the Activesheet, you get an error.

Why does it happen when a sheet already exists? Probably because while troubleshooting your code you went to the UI, created the sheet, then back to the code to run it. You left that newly created Topline sheet active and when Topline and Activesheet are the same thing, no error.

Comment: The `Worksheets.Add` line always makes the newly-added sheet the Activesheet - there's nothing in the code which would switch to another sheet, so that would explain why it never fails if the Topline sheet needs to be added,

Comment: Right. I had that backward. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I knew it was something exceptionally simple. I've added the Topline. qualifier to the relevant cell references and it's working like a charm now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

The first issue was at:-

```
.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(7, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
```

And the issue was that `Cells(1, 1)` returns a range but `.Range(x, y)` expects just an address, i.e. `Cells(1,1).AddressLocal`.

If you amend all your: -

```
.Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(x, y))
```

entries to: -

```
    .Range(Cells(x, y).AddressLocal, Cells(x, y).AddressLocal))
```

You should get closer to a working answer. I came to another issue at:-

```
Data.Range(Cells(x + 2, 1).AddressLocal, Cells(x + a, 3).AddressLocal).Copy
```

But I believe this is a separate issue caused by only getting a snippet of code or lack of option explicit with definition over `x` and `a`.

Comment: Did not Downvote, but the first half of this answer is ***wrong***.  `Range` *does* accept another `Range` as arguments, not just an address string.  `Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(2,2))` is perfectly valid, and is the same as `Range("A1","B2")` or `Range("A1:B2")`.  The second half is only quarter-right:  the *fully qualified* reference would be `Data.Range(Data.Cells(x + 2, 1), Data.Cells(x + a, 3)).Copy` or `.Range(.Cells(x + 2, 1), .Cells(x + a, 3)).Copy` - you need to define the Worksheet for the `Cells` as well as the `Range`, but within a `With Data` you only need the `.` and not `Data.`